# Method using the calling object's "self" by default

Tags: swift

I have a utility class containing functions that are used by multiple other classes.  One of those is an alert function:

```
class Utils {
    func doAlert (title: String, message: String, target: UIViewController) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        target.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This function will always target `self` on the view controller, so I'd like to not have to add `target: self` every time I call the function, but I can't just set it as a default value since that causes it to refer back to the `Utils` class.  Is there any way I can rewrite this to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utility classes are an antipattern exactly for this reason, what you really want to use is an `extension`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func doAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and then you can call the method directly on all your controllers:

```
self.doAlert(title: "title", message: "message")
```

In general avoid classes with utility methods. Try to add methods to the types to which the functionality actually belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the function in your Utils class, you could put it in an extension to UIViewController, like this:

```
    extension UIViewController {
        func doAlert (title: String, message: String) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            target.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
```